# Youtube API onYoutubePlayerReady and addEventListener not being triggered

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, addeventlistener, youtube-javascript-api

Youtube API's onYoutubePlayerReady() & addEventListener("onstatechange"...) functions aren't being triggered when youtube videos are loaded on my site

->This code is hosted on a web server at http://www.vapetropolis.ca/handheld-portable-vaporizers

->An alert should pop-up when the videos load - I've tried implementing the alert through both onYoutubePlayerReady and addEventListener("onStateChange"...) without success.

Any help is very much appreciated

Here's what I have so far - all of this code is in one .phtml file:

```
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
```

Trying to alert onYoutubePlayerReady...

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
   alert("READY");
}

  </script>
```

There are multiple videos: divs are created in a foreach loop. The bulk of this code is removed for readability

```
<div id="videoDiv-<?php echo $_product->getName();?>"></div>
```

Adding products/video IDs to a javascript array

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    window.productVideos = {
        //Product Name : Youtube Video Id
    };

    productVideos["Volcano Vaporizer - Classic or Digital"] = "ukHcyEMxBEE";
    productVideos["Iolite Original Vaporizer"] = "WaVSuJ0DH7c";
    productVideos["Iolite Wispr Vaporizer"] = "OTCN-bl10f0";


    var productNames = new Array(
        <?php $count = 0; foreach($_productCollection as $_product ) {
            if ($count > 0) echo ',';
            echo '"' . $_product->getName() . '"';
            $count++;
        }?>
    );
```

Iterating through product array, loading associated videos (this works fine)

```
    var iterator;
    for (iterator = 0; iterator < <?php echo $_productCollection->count(); ?>; iterator++) {
        if (productVideos[productNames[iterator]]) {
            loadPlayer(productNames[iterator], productVideos[productNames[iterator]]);
        }
    }


});
```

Trying to attach an event listener to the video - this isn't working

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {

    for (var index in window.productVideos) {

        if (document.getElementById("ytPlayer-" + window.productVideos[index])) {
            document.getElementById("ytPlayer-" + window.productVideos[index]).addEventListener("onStateChange", "alert");

        }
    }
});

</script>
```

Various irrelevant functions

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
                    /**
 * Resizing the player in JavaScript.
 */

function alert() {
    alert("HI");
}


// Make the player small.
function smallPlayer() {
  resizePlayer(480, 295);
}

// Set the player back to normal.
function normalPlayer() {
  resizePlayer(560, 340);
}

// Make the player big.
function largePlayer() {
  resizePlayer(640, 385);
}

function onPlayerStateChange() {
      resizePlayer(560, 340);
}

// Set the loaded player to a specific height and width.
function resizePlayer(width, height, videoID) {
  var playerObj = document.getElementById("ytPlayer-" + videoID);
  jQuery("#yt-player-" + videoID).parents('li').height('600px');
  playerObj.height = height;
  playerObj.width = width;
}
```

Function to load videos - called above

```
// The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
function loadPlayer(productName, videoID) {

  //jQuery("videoDiv-" + productName).parents('li').height('600px');
  // The video to load
  //var videoID = "ylLzyHk54Z0";
  // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
  var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always"};
  // The element id of the Flash embed
  var atts = { id: "ytPlayer-" + videoID, class: "ytplayer"};
  // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
  swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/" + videoID + 
                     "?version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                     "videoDiv-" + productName, "140", "85", "9", null, null, params, atts); 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify unique `playerapiid` for each player. I suggest you to simplify your  `loadPlayer` function a little bit to accept two arguments:

```
function loadPlayer(blockID, videoID) {
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+videoID+'?autostart=0&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid='+blockID,
        blockID, '320', '200', '8', null, null,
        { allowScriptAccess: 'always', wmode: 'transparent' },
        { id: blockID, name: blockID }
    );
}
```

Starting with single player, making it work with API is really important before writing code that manage several players, because its easier to make it work.

Working JSFiddle using this function: http://jsfiddle.net/rbRF3/